# Entity Framework Core + SQlite. Async requests are actually synchronous

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I have WPF program and I am trying to use EF Core with SQLite there and I found strange behaviour. Even if I call async method like ToArrayAsync() or SaveChangesAsync() it returns already completed task. So it means that operation was actually done synchronously.

It seems that there should be some flag in EF or SQLite connection which control sync/async execution but I didn't find it.

I used this code for tests:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    //I have about 10000 records here.
    var task = context.Users.ToListAsync();
    if (task.IsCompleted && task.Result != null)
    {
        // It is always comes here.
    }
    await task;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested with a Task that you know will not complete in a short amount of time? ie. ensuring that the Users table has a large number of records (maybe something over 100 would do?)?

Comment: @Igor the comment says 10000 records

Comment: @mxmissile - I missed that.

Comment: @Igor I'm wondering if `ToListAsync()` actually starts the task? If so, you might be on to something.

Comment: Using [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx), is there a significant time difference between calling `ToListAsync`, `task.IsCompleted` and then inside the `if`?

Comment: What happens if you use task.Result? Will it return result immediately? I suspect that IsCompleted does not represent the actual state of the task for some reason.

Comment: @mxmissile - yes, the task is started.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that in .NET 4.6 console application (should not make a difference with WPF) and EF core.

Comment: Is the task immediately completing *with an error?*

Comment: IsCompleted can represent three states:  RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled. Might want to also look at the Status.

Comment: @StephenCleary No there was no error. And it already has a result.

Comment: @Evk could you give me a link to your sample so I could find the difference? Or I can give you mine tomorrow.

Comment: My sample is completely identical to yours. IsCompleted branch is never entered and if I later wait on 'task' - it still takes more than a second to complete. Try to measure each line of your code with  Stopwatch and tell us the results. Try to create fresh console app and see if you can reproduce there. If not - find minimal example which reproduces it for you.

Comment: @Evk I tried with fresh console app and the result is the same. I've added a link to source code in the question's description. Any help, comments or pull requests is highly appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm your example works as you are saying with SQLite, but cannot confirm it works the same with sql server, while you are saying that "I tried with different data providers (MSSQL, Sqlite, SqlCE) and they all have the same problem".

Comment: Thanks @Evk! May be my tests with MSSQL was not so Accurate. I am going to change question's description. But it is still open because I have the prioblem with SQLite at least.

Comment: @IvanChepikov async doesn't mean parallel or running on a different thread. It means that you don't have to wait while a truly asynchronous operation runs, eg IO. SQLite is an embedded database, working on your own process and using your application's threads. The provider may not support asynchronous operations. Async certainly doesn't make sense when working with an in-memory database. It *may* offer some benefits when working with files. How did you open the database?

Comment: @IvanChepikov anyway, EFCore itself doesn't perform the asynchronous IO operation. That's the job of the provider.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand all you said. If you provide a link that says that SQLite provider supports only synchronous operations it will be a good answer for my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because SQLite implementations of ADO.NET classes (`DbConnection`, `DbCommand`) are synchronous. Parent classes provide `Async` methods that are really synchronous, and it's a job of provider to provide better implementation. For example, here is implementatation of `DbConnection.OpenAsync`:

```
public virtual Task OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  TaskCompletionSource<object> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    completionSource.SetCanceled();
  }
  else
  {
    try
    {
      this.Open();
      completionSource.SetResult((object) null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      completionSource.SetException(ex);
    }
  }
  return (Task) completionSource.Task;
}
```

As you see, there is nothing asynchronous whatsover, and returned task is always completed.

The same goes for all default `Async` implementations in `DbCommand`: they all either use `TaskCompletionSource` or directly `Task.FromResult`.

SQLiteCommand does not override that behavior, and when it does - it says explicitly in comments to the methods that asynchronous execution is not supported. For example, here is implementation (overriden) of `ExecuteReaderAsync`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes the <see cref="P:Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.CommandText" /> asynchronously against the database and returns a data reader.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="behavior">A description of query's results and its effect on the database.</param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">The token to monitor for cancellation requests.</param>
/// <returns>A task representing the asynchronous operation.</returns>
/// <remarks>
/// SQLite does not support asynchronous execution. Use write-ahead logging instead.
/// </remarks>
/// <seealso href="http://sqlite.org/wal.html">Write-Ahead Logging</seealso>
public virtual Task<SqliteDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  return Task.FromResult<SqliteDataReader>(this.ExecuteReader(behavior));
}
```

By contrast - `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` classes do override default (synchornous) behavior and provide really asynchronous implementations of methods like `OpenAsync` or `ExecuteReaderAsync`, so with sql server provider you should not have the behavior you observe.

So the behavior you observe is expected and not buggy when using SQLite.

Since you are using this in WPF application - that would mean that despite using async\await you UI thread will be blocked for the duration of the whole opration. So best thing to do in this case is not not use async versions at all and dispatch whole thing to the background thread via `Task.Run` or similar construct.

Comment: I'd add that asynchronous execution doesn't make sense with an *in-memory* database, which is probably why SQLite doesn't provide such an implementation. There's nothing async with RAM access. Processing in the background can be performed with `Task.Run`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but SQLite is file database, not purely RAM database?

Comment: works in both modes. It's not meant to be a server or multiuser database. They could, eg check the mode and change the behaviour of the async methods accordingly but that would lead to further confusion. I'm not sure the SQLite C library offers async operations anyway

Comment: Looks like SQLite [dropped async IO](https://www.sqlite.org/asyncvfs.html) in favor of Write Ahead Logging.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos seems so, that is exactly what is stated in xml comments to their async methods (like the method I provided in answer): "SQLite does not support asynchronous execution. Use write-ahead logging instead."