# UI is not updated while property is updated in MVVM WPF MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

This question was answered many times but it seems it's something different.
I implemented [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) and async command handler as suggested [here](https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/), so my command handler in the ViewModel looks like this:

```
    public async Task CommandAsync()
    {
        StatusText = "Process started...";
        await myApp.LongRunningProcess().ConfigureAwait(false);
        StatusText = "Process finished...";
    }
```

The problem is that "Process started..." is not showed up, it goes directly to the "Process finished..." even if my process works really long. StatusText shows nothing during process running. However, if I add this micro-delay, it starts to work as expected! I do not understand, why.

```
    public async Task CommandAsync()
    {
        StatusText = "Process started...";
        await Task.Delay(1); <--- Now everything works!
        await myApp.LongRunningProcess().ConfigureAwait(false);
        StatusText = "Process finished...";
    }
```

Note that without async/await I can't get a message "Process started..." at all - it seems like my long process blocks the UI thread earlier than message is able to render. Could it be the problem with MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit and some rendering specifics? I don't like found solution with `Task.Delay(1)` because it works for unknown reason so it can fail in some other circumstances.

Comment: And without `.ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: The same. It makes no difference. I added it to indicate that I tried to take care about running my process in a separate context.

Comment: You certainly want to get back into the UI thread after the asynchronous call has finished, so you should not set ConfigureAwait(false).

Comment: Can you show how your `LongRunningProcess` looks like? I would check if this method start new `Task` or call a method which works on own Task/Thread.

Comment: I would also guess, that your `LongRunningProcess` is not using Tasks properly. If so, a workaround is to use it like: `await Task.Run(() => myApp.LongRunningProcess().GetAwaiter().GetResult());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand, why.

Most probably because the *implementation* of `myApp.LongRunningProcess()` is not asynchronous and blocks the UI thread.

This has nothing to do with MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit "and some rendering specifics".

You need to make sure that `myApp.LongRunningProcess()` doesn't block.

If you replace  `await myApp.LongRunningProcess().ConfigureAwait(false);` with `await Task.Delay(2000)` and you then see the "Process started..." message, you know that the implementation of `myApp.LongRunningProcess()` is indeed the issue.

A method is not automatically asynchronous just because it returns a `Task` or a `Task<T>`.

Comment: Yes, you right, myApp.LongRunningProcess() blocks UI. This process asks SQL and returns Task<List> where List = await context.ToListAsync() and myApp added to ViewModel via Microsoft DI. Why does it still block UI??

Comment: Found it. This is because EF to SQLLite implementation is synchronous. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982444/entity-framework-core-sqlite-async-requests-are-actually-synchronous Task.Run as pointed out by @Klamsi helps.