# UI Thread blocked when calling an async method (Blazor WASM PWA)

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Can anyone help me to understand why the following code is blocking the UI thread...

I've modified the sample application from https://github.com/TrevorDArcyEvans/BlazorSQLiteWasm in order to test the performance of the SQLite database inside a Blazor WebAssembly Progressive Web Application

On a .razor file I have the following

```
<button onclick="@(async () => CreateMany())" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
   Insert Many
</button>
```

Which references:

```
private async void CreateMany()
{
    var cars = new List<Car>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {             
        cars.Add(new() { Brand = "BMW", Price = 500 });
    }

    var db = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
    await db.Cars.AddRangeAsync(cars);

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    _cars.Clear();
    _cars.AddRange(db.Cars);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

When I click the "Insert Many" button it seems to ignore the fact the it's an async void, and it blocks the UI anyway. Am I missing something here?

.NET 6.0

Comment: I've tried adding await Task.Delay(2000); as the first line in the CreateMany() method, this has the effect of waiting 2 seconds before doing the database work, the UI doesn't block until after the two seconds, so the async/await is clearly working, perhaps there is something inside the entity framework blocking the thread...

Comment: nowadays there are background workers on the web, but they're not useable as threads for blazor. so the reason it's blocking the UI thread is, that there is no other thread to use.

Comment: Duplicate. Search around a little before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982444/entity-framework-core-sqlite-async-requests-are-actually-synchronous

Comment: hm i actually see right now it seems some browsers have already implemented multithreading support, however blazor support is still underway [Real multithreading (on supported browsers) #17730](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17730)

Comment: Maybe `async Task`, instead of `void`?

Answer (score 2):

> `onclick="@(async () => CreateMany())"`

This will give you a "... is not awaited" Warning after a Build. Just use `onclick="CreateMany"`

> Am I missing something here?

It would have been *better* to use `async Task CreateMany() ...` but that is not essential.

The main problem is that Sqlite is totally synchronous. `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` is a lie, it is not async at all.

So your code would probably work as expected with a different database, but there is not much on offer in Wasm.

`Task.Run()` is also not effective, so alas, you're stuck with this.